# Site redirection to Auth0 does not apply to Googlebot

Tags: web-crawler, redirect

I've come across a site which automatically redirects the user to a 3rd-party website, but noticed that webcrawlers like Googlebot were not subject to the redirection, meaning that the actual content of the site could be accessed by the webcrawlers. This results in:

1. Google listing individual pages of that site as search results. The actual content can be viewed from the Google cache, but the user is redirected to an unrelated site (as mentioned above) if he clicks on the search result links.
2. If the user uses archive sites like the Wayback Machine, he is able to manually cache the actual content of the site as retrieved by the Wayback Machine's crawler, then browse the site normally albeit as a static cached version.

I suspect this has something to do with Auth0, as the site imports an Auth0 script, but I'm not sure how Auth0 actually works.

My questions are as follows:

1. How is the site administrator doing this? How was he able to block and redirect normal access yet allowing webcrawlers to get through, whether intentionally or otherwise?
2. How, then, does the site administrator access his own site normally? What kind of security settings could he have possibly implemented for the site?

As this is a rather vague question due to not revealing the actual website, I'm sure there are several possibilities for its implementation based on my description, and I would love to hear what you guys think. This investigation is purely out of personal curiosity and interest.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for a web application to verify if it's being accessed by Googlebot or other Google user-agents, this would allow the server to provide custom content and/or allow access to pages that would normally require authentication.

See [Verifying Googlebot](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=en) for instructions.